# Android Studio only reads defined QR codes in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, qr-code

I don't want Android Studio to scan QR codes other than those defined in the application and I want to do this with CameraView.

Instead of downloading or installing a library, I want to scan the defined qr code via the phone's camera.

Comment: Android's `CameraView` is not the same as any default camera app on a device which might/might not handle QR codes.

Comment: So which class should be used to detect QR defined QR Codes?

Comment: If you want to run the camera within your own app, and want to scan QR codes, you'll have to use a library like ZXing or MLKit. There is no formal way of returning the contents of a QR code is via Android Intent. Any example you find uses a known second camera/barcode reader app that will need to be installed in addition to your own.

Comment: So can't it be done without using these packages?

Comment: Android framework has no default/built-in barcode scanning/processing functions. ZXing is open source so you are free to inspect/modify the code as you need. Do realize that the Android developer ecosystem is built with many libraries, both from Google and third-party developers.

Comment: A few years ago, when there was no ZXing package, there was a method of placing a QR code in the application and opening the data if it was the same QR code read by the camera.